# Why am I receiving a 404 error during Stripe Web Hook Test

Tags: api, asp.net-core, stripe-payments

I created an endpoint in Stripe https://www.websitename.com/StripeWebHook/Index but when I test it I get a 404 error (tried the endpoint without index too). In the example code for the StripeWebHook class, it says to label it as an api. [Route("api/[controller]")] public class StripeWebHook : Controller. Am I missing something in the Startup/Program file or am I calling the Index incorrectly?

**Startup Class**

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });





            services.AddDbContext<Models.CContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));



            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CContext>();

            //added this to fix CarRepository error
            services.AddScoped<ICartRepository, CartRepository>();


            services.AddSession();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);


        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>//This whole thing is random exception stuff
                {
                    errorApp.Run(async context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("<html lang=\"en\"><body>\r\n");
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("ERROR!<br><br>\r\n");

                        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
                            context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

                        // Use exceptionHandlerPathFeature to process the exception (for example, 
                        // logging), but do NOT expose sensitive error information directly to 
                        // the client.

                        if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error is FileNotFoundException)
                        {
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync("File error thrown!<br><br>\r\n");
                        }

                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("<a href=\"/\">Home</a><br>\r\n");
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("</body></html>\r\n");
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(new string(' ', 512)); // IE padding
                    });
                    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                });
                }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            //app.UseStaticFiles();

            // This will add "Libs" as another valid static content location


        }
    }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Controllers
{


   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class StripeWebHook : Controller
    {
        // You can find your endpoint's secret in your webhook settings
        const string secret = "whsec_....";

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_....";
            var json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            try
            {
                var stripeEvent = EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json,
                    Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], secret);
                // Handle the checkout.session.completed event
                if (stripeEvent.Type == Events.CheckoutSessionCompleted)
                {
                    var session = stripeEvent.Data.Object as Stripe.Checkout.Session;

                    // Fulfill the purchase...
                    //HandleCheckoutSession(session);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Ok();
                };
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (StripeException e)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if my answer didn't solve your problem please add the code of your statup.cs class.

Comment: please share you startup.cs and the StripeWebHook controller on the question. It will help us to undestand how your routes are configured.

Comment: I think the issue was that I was testing the wrong files so when the api routing was there it worked using website/api/stripwebhook/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since configured Route attribute as `api/[controller]`, you can't access the StripeWebHook controller directly. You need to configure stripe to use websitename.com/api/StripeWebHook.

Answer (score 0):

`https://www.websitename.com/StripeWebHook/Index` call the `GET` action named `Index` in `StripeWebHookController` while you have decorated Index action with a `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Try to remove both `[Route("api/[controller]")]` and `[HttpPost]` attributes in your above code and test again.

```
public class StripeWebHook : Controller
{

    //[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
    }
}
```